# When to use json and when jsonp with jquery $.ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, jsonp

In our site, Some pages are SSL and some are non-SSL.

For Example:

```
http://www.example.com/search/patients
https://www.example.com/patients
```

Now I am searching patients on `http://www.example.com/search/patients` page and send server request to `https://www.example.com/patients` via `jQuery $.ajax` function and `dataType=json`. I am unable to get data.

**Questions:**

1. Should I use `jsonp` when we request from `http` to `https` or `https` to `http` on same server?
2. If I use SSL for both URLs then will it work with `dataType=json` only

Thanks

Comment: I guess AJAX requests can be made by relative path instead of absolute path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) your ajax request is allowed only if:
domain name, application layer protocol, and (in most browsers) port
number of the HTML document running the script are the same

**In your case the application layer protocol is different, that's why your script fails**.

Possible solutions are:

- [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which has to be provided by the server
- [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), which is a more 'elegant' and clean solution, but is not yet fully supported by IE (IE7 doesn't support it, IE8 has some limitations)

Answer (score 3):

If you use SSL for both URLs it should work. Also as @Waqas Raja suggested, it would be better to use relative URLS.

e.g. `$.ajax({url: '/search/patients'})`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either CORS, a proxy or JSONP to get content from a different origin. Changing scheme (from http to https or the other way around) is changing origin.

Pulling data from a secure server into an insecure page eliminates many of the benefits of using SSL.

If you fetch both the page and the data source over SSL then you can use plain JSON and don't introduce those security problems.