# consuming PHP service returning valid json with $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I've been stuck on consuming a web service created in PHP, not sure what I'm doing wrong.. Ive created a fiddle example here : http://jsfiddle.net/e97AV/
I've tried *various combinations* of things but keep on getting 404 not found feedback, when I specify jsonp i get no error message, but in the web console i can see a 404 error.. in the browser when I visit the url it is returning valid json

My question is how would I know when to use jsonp or json? Also these service have been provided to me from an external source other than agreeing on json being returned how would I know if the problem is on my side or theirs?

heres the ajax code

```
baseUrl = "http://exclusivegetaways.co.za/api.php";
    $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET",
            url: baseUrl,
            data: {something : "something"},
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("works");
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (a,b,cc) {
                alert(a+b+cc);
            }
        });
```

I've since been able to pull json data from the **ajax error object**?? like so:

```
baseUrl = "http://exclusivegetaways.co.za/api.php?something=something";

$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: baseUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (res) {
        alert("worked");
        //alert(res);
    },
    error: function(jqxhr) {
        try {        
            f = JSON.parse(jqxhr.responseText);
        ...valid json returned here

        } catch(err) {alert(err);}
    }
});
```

Comment: Please check this url, this question is asked previously.

[When to use json and when jsonp with jquery $.ajax?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311821/when-to-use-json-and-when-jsonp-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: I didnt know about the Access-Control thing can I get passed it somehow? Im trying to create a mobile app so its not gonna be on the same domain. As for the browser it picks up the url no problem, I even checked the result in jsonlint.

Comment: What simulator are you using for the mobile app. For android emulator i had the same problem, but tested on device it works fine.

Comment: Both xcode and android giving no results.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a security restriction that prevents Ajax from querying remote locations.

As a workaround to enable access to a remote location via Ajax, you could build a custom URL in your webApp (in PHP for instance) which queries the distant API and returns JSON.

Then, in your JavaScript, you call this URL (from **your** application) via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

First: Always look at your JavaScript error console.

> ```
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://exclusivegetaways.co.za/api.php?location=provinces.
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
> Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
> ```

See also [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

---

> I've tried various combinations of things but keep on getting 404 not found feedback, when I specify jsonp i get no error message, but in the web console i can see a 404 error. in the browser when I visit the url it is returning valid json

This suggests that:

- They don't support JSONP
- They look at the HTTP headers and 404 your request to block access from Ajax (this isn't a good way to do that, the error code is misleading)

---

> My question is how would I know when to use jsonp or json?

Usually by reading the documentation for the server you are trying to use

---

> Also these service have been provided to me from an external source other than agreeing on json being returned how would I know if the problem is on my side or theirs?

Usually by working with whatever support is provided by the API provider (i.e. start with their documentation, then fall back to whatever means they provide for communicating with a human).

Answer (score -1):

Due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) your ajax request is allowed only if:
domain name, application layer protocol, and (in most browsers) port
number of the HTML document running the script are the same

**In your case the application layer protocol is different, that's why your script fails**.

Possible solutions are:

- [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which has to be provided by the server
- [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), which is a more 'elegant' and clean solution, but is not yet fully supported by IE (IE7 doesn't support it, IE8 has some limitations)

[Answer taken from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311821/when-to-use-json-and-when-jsonp-with-jquery-ajax/10311935#10311935)